# How to fix "Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: " error in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to create a records with multiple one to one relationships in laravel 5.7. The following is how I am doing it,

**Migrations**

```php
   //in create_invoices_table.php
   public function up()
     {
           Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->integer('service_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->integer('account_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();

                // foreign keys
                $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('account_id')->references('id')->on('accounts')->onDelete('cascade');
           });
     }


     // in create_accounts_table.php
     public function up()
     {
         Schema::create('accounts', function (Blueprint $table){
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('name');
              $table->string('email');
              $table->timestamps()
         )};
     }


     // in the create_services_table.php
     public function up()
     {
          Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table){
              $table->increments('id');
              $table->string('name');
              $table->float('price', 8, 2);
              $table->timestamps();
         )};
     }
```

**Models**

The `Account` model has a `hasOne()` function which defines a one to one relationship with the invoices. i.e.

```
   //in Account.php
   public function invoice() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
   }
```

The `Service` model has a `hasOne()` function which defines a one to one relationship with the invoices as well. i.e.

```
   //in Service.php
   public function invoice() {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Invoice');
   }
```

The inverses one to one relationshipa are defined in the `invoice model` using the `belongsTo()` functions as follows

```
     //in Invoice.php
     public function account() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
     }

     public function service() {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
     }
```

**InvoiceController.php**

Now I am trying to create an invoice record which I am trying to associate with the `account` as well as `service` models as follows

```
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
          $account = Account::find([$request->get('aid')]);
          $service = Service::find([$request->get('sid')]);

          $invoice = new Invoice();
          $invoice->name = self::getAccountName($request->get('aid'));

          // save the invoice to database
          $invoice->save();

          // add service and account to the invoice
          $invoice->account()->associate($account)->save();
          $invoice->service()->associate($service)->save();


          return redirect()->route('invoices.index');
     }
```

And this give me the following error which I am failing to fix.

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (22007) SQLSTATE[22007]:
>   Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:
>   '[{"id":1,"name":"Example Name","email":"example@email.com"' for column 'account_id' at row 1 (SQL: update `invoices` set `account_id` = [{"id":1,"name":"Example Name","email":"example@email.com","created_at":"2019-01-02 15:37:41","updated_at":"2019-01-02 15:37:41"}], `updated_at` = 2019-01-02 16:05:13 where `id` = 17)

Please, help me how I can fix this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to remove the square brackets in find. Eloquent find will return a collection if you pass an array as parameter.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
      $account = Account::find($request->get('aid')); // remove square brackets around $request
      $service = Service::find($request->get('sid')); // remove square brackets around $request

      $invoice = new Invoice();
      $invoice->name = self::getAccountName($request->get('aid'));

      // add service and account to the invoice
      $invoice->account()->associate($account); // remove save()
      $invoice->service()->associate($service); // remove save()

      // save the invoice to database
      $invoice->save();


      return redirect()->route('invoices.index');
 }
```

Also save after you associate all relations to avoid multiple database transactions.

Comment: Well, I have tried this. but it is not working. I am still getting the same error. I have also tried to do `dd($invoice->toArray())` before calling the `save()` method and it shows that the association are working fine.

Comment: Well it works now, after removing the square brackets